# type is not visible - getter method

Tags: java, junit, getter

```
public class car {
private String make;
private String model;
private int mileage;
private int year;
private float price;

public car(String make, String model, int mileage, int year, float price) {
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.mileage = mileage;
    this.year = year;
    this.price = price;
} 

private String getMake() {
    return make;
}

private String getModel() {
    return model;
}

private int getMileage() {
    return mileage;
}

private int getYear() {
    return year;
}

private float getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public String toString() {
    return "Make:"+getMake()+"\nModel:"+getModel()+"\nMileage:"+getMileage()+"\nYear:"+getYear()+"\nPrice:"+getPrice();
}



class carTest {
private String[] carToStringArray(car c) {
    String[] carInfo = {c.getMake(), c.getModel(), Integer.toString(c.getMileage()), 
            Integer.toString(c.getYear()), Integer.toString(c.getPrice())};
    return carInfo;
}

@Test
void verifyCarEqualityWithMakeModelYear() {
    String[] expected = {"Toyota", "RAV4", "2018"};
    car actual = new car("Honda", "Altima",45000, 2015, 12000);
    assertArrayEquals(expected, carToStringArray(actual));
}
```

}

I have error at carToStringArray(). There is red underline at c.getMake(), c.getModel(), c.getMileage(),
c.getYear(), c.getPrice(). I got an error msg that 'The method getMake() from the type car is not visible' but I have this method at car class. Can I know what is wrong with my test code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing your getter methods from outside of the class, then you need to change the visibility. E.g. to `public`:

```java
public String getMake() {
    return make;
}
```

You can read more about it on the [official java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

Answer (score 0):

`getMake`, `getModel`, `getMileage` and other such methods - these are all called getters. And in your code, the access-modifier that you're using for these is `private`. This means that these getters will not be accessible outside of this class.

If you want to call these methods from outside of these class, you'll have to elevate the access modifier.

Generally we make getters `public` - but this is just a convention, and there's no strict rule that mandates you to do that.

Read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) article to get a detailed understanding of this topic.

Answer (score 0):

All the getters are `private`, so they can't be used from outside the class. You should define them as `public`, or at least have default visibility, assuming that `car` and `carTest` are in the same package.